# How to use Django template in ReactJS

Tags: django, reactjs

I am using broswerify to translate my jsx code. But how can I insert Django template variable to react code after it has been converted to javascript? For example:

In my Django views.py:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', {"hello":"hello"})
```

In component.jsx

```
var React = require('react')
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var Component = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>{this.props.content}</div>
        );
    },
});
```

Then use `browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ react ] ] component.jsx -o bundle.js` to convert `component.jsx` to `bundle.js`.

In index.html:

```
<html>
...
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>

    <div id="container"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
      ReactDOM.render(
        <Component content={{hello}} />,
        document.getElementById('container')
      );
    </script>
</body>

<html>
```

The problem is that in index.html, the browser complains that `<Component>` is undefined since browserify has transformed jsx into original javascript code.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser  can help

Answer (score 0):

You should move the ''ReactDOM.render'' thing to a seaparate ''index.jsx'' file or whatever the entrypoint for your react app is. The ''{{hello}}'' variable should be put on the window object so it can be accessed by the react components